# How can I incorpoarte Fortify Scan Analyzer with Apache Ant in a Unix Makefile?

Tags: java, unix, makefile, ant, fortify

I am currently trying to add Fortify Scan Analyzer to Apache Ant build written in a Makefile. So far, the Makefile looks like:

`default: foo.jar temp.jar bar.jar
    @ant jar-fake`

In the documentation for Fortify in Chapter 13: Integration into Build, it has a section on Ant Integration. It simply states:

"To use the Ant integration, make sure that the sourceanalyzer executable is on the system PATH.
Prepend your Ant command-line with the sourceanalyzer command as follows:

`sourceanalyzer -b <build_id> ant [<ant_options>]`"

This does not work.

I have also tried the Touchless Build Intergration option:
"Fortify Static Code Analyzer includes a generic build tool called touchless that enables translation of
projects using build systems that Fortify Static Code Analyzer does not directly support. The commandline syntax for touchless build integration is:

`sourceanalyzer -b <build_id> touchless <build_command>` "

This also does not work. It only works outside of a Makefile.

I need a way to incorporate the Fortify Scan Analyzer in the Makefile working with Ant.

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of files is ant compiling for you? The SCA Ant integration will only pickup calls to the javac task as mentioned in the docs.

Comment: There is a build.xml file in the same directory as the unix Makefile. In the Makefile, there are targets that have the `@ant` tag that Apache Ant picks up, then refers to the build.xml to build the java files into packaged jars. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: So you do have calls to `javac` in the build.xml files somewhere? e.g.         ```<javac source="1.5" target="1.5" debug="true" destdir="${build.classes.dir}">
            <classpath refid="build.classpath"/>
            <src location="${src.dir}"/>
        </javac>```

Comment: Correct. In the `<classpath refid="${fortify path}" />`, could I call a different property that would have the file location for the fortify scan analyzer?

Comment: SCA should pick up calls to javac from ant... are you running a clean on the ant build first? If the classes are already built, ant will not re-build them, and therefore SCA won't pick up anything. Maybe try a `sourceanalyzer -b test ant clean compile` or some other target that will invoke the javac calls?

Comment: Your suggestion involves a command line argument that is not in the unix Makefile or build.xml. I need to be able to call sourceanalyzer without it being user dependent. For example, if you are building a C++ application, you can use:

`CC=sourceanalyzer -b mybuild gcc
CXX=sourceanalyzer -b mybuild g++
LD=sourceanalyzer -b mybuild ld
AR=sourceanalyzer -b mybuild ar `

in the Makefile. It does not require a user to enter the command via commandline.

Comment: Right. Wrapping calls to ant in your Makefile to `ANT=sourceanalyzer -b test ant` should allow SCA to pick up any `javac` invocations from the subsequent ant calls though; but only if there were any javac calls, which don't run if the classes are already built, which is why I asked if you cleaned first. Is the lack of consistency across builds what made the `sourceanalyzer -b <build_id> ant [<ant_options>]` approach not viable?

Comment: I am doing the following:

`sourceanalyzer -b test ant /n
@ant jar-fake `

in my Makefile. It build successfully by source analyzer reports errors like missing java libraries and variables.

Comment: Remove the `@` from `@ant` -- it's a `make` directive.

Comment: Removing `@` from `@ant` causes an error in the overall build. That does not work. Thanks